# Postfix - sender dependent default transport maps

Tags: postfix

Have this feature configured, in main.cf

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender
```

in `relay_by_sender` file -

```
@a.b.com relay:[1.2.3.4]:26
```

Now I want to add another line in "relay_by_sender" file to forward all other emails to a different smart host.

I have tried below, but emails with sender domain other than @a.b.com won't get forwarded to 11.22.33.44.

```
@a.b.com relay:[1.2.3.4]:26
* relay:[11.22.33.44]:25
```

Can anyone tell me why the above code is not working?

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more legible and easier to understand. Use the formatting tools, break it into parts and expand on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with not having an `@` in front of the `*`, but I'm curious why you're not using `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`... if all you're doing is changing who you're relaying to, I'm pretty sure `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` is overkill.